# "Install new software" button disappeared from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

The help menu in Eclipse has no "Install new software" button so I can't install any new plugins:

[image]

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. Here's my Eclipse version:

```
Eclipse Platform
Version: 4.3.2.v20140221-1852
Build id: M20140221-1700
```

Answer (score 6):

I do not have a solution, but I figured out this workaround.

1. Go to Help/Search
2. Search for "Install new"
3. Select "Updating and installing software" from the local search results.
4. Click on the link by the name "Installing new software"
5. Here click the first link with the text "Help > Install New Software ..."

This opens up the dialog for installing.
For me this happened today after installing a bunch of plugins from oracle and jboss

Best of luck

Comment: Holly molly!! this worked perfectly!!! Thanks man this answer helped a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Run as Administrator.

Either Shift-Enter the program or right-click. The problem should be solved immediately.